# Why does EXPLAIN return different Extra (filesort) based on user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two users, `root` and `readonly`. The grants look like this:

```sql
mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'readonly'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Grants for readonly@localhost                 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'readonly'@'localhost' |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I have a SELECT query which, when EXPLAIN'd with the `readonly` user returns this:

```sql
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mv_store | range | my_key        | my_key | 768     | NULL | 7878512 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

But, when EXPLAIN'd with the `root` user returns this:

```sql
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mv_store | range | my_key        | my_key | 768     | NULL | 7878512 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

Note the missing `filesort` for the root user.

After trawling through some of the mysql docs I can't reasonably guess at why `filesort` would be present for the `readonly` user but absent for the `root` user, other than the root user is doing *something* that requires extra permissions. But it's not obvious to me what those would be, or how I would discover them.

Here's the ([jooq](https://www.jooq.org/) generated) query:

```sql
select 
  `key_col1`,
  `key_col2`,
  `key_col3`,
  `key_col4`, 
  `not_in_key1`,
  `not_in_key2`,
  `not_in_key3`,
  `not_in_key4`
from 
  `tbl` force index (`my_key`) 
where 
(`key_col2` in ('value1') 
  and `not_in_key1` in (0) 
  and `not_in_key2` is null 
  and (1 = 0 or `key_col1` > '0' 
    or (`key_col2` > 'value1' and `key_col1` = '0') 
    or (`key_col3` > -9223372036854775808 and `key_col2` = 'value1' and `key_col1` = '0') 
    or (`key_col4` > '' and `key_col3` = -9223372036854775808 and `key_col2` = 'value1' and `key_col1` = '0')) 
  and 1 = 1) 

order by 
`tbl`.`key_col1` asc, `tbl`.`key_col2` asc, `tbl`.`key_col3` asc, `tbl`.`key_col4` asc limit 1000;
```

And the `my_key` covers `(key_col1, key_col2, key_col3, key_col4)`.

EDIT: So running `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and then `SHOW WARNINGS` (as explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-extended.html)) reveals that the `root` user's query has dropped `key_col2` from the `ORDER BY`. I.e. the order line reads:

```sql
order by `tbl`.`key_col1` asc, `tbl`.`key_col3` asc, `tbl`.`key_col4` asc
```

I guess this makes sense since it is held constant by the `IN` clause. If I do an explain with the new statement and the `readonly` user, it is optimised.

Why can the `root` user optimise the query this way but not the `readonly` user?

Comment: "Using filesort" means it can't find a suitable index that satisfies both the Where and the Order By clauses. What columns does my_key index contain?

Comment: I've clarified the question to ask why the readonly user uses filesort but the root user does not.

Also added what my_key covers

Comment: Columns not_in_key1 and not_in_key2 are not in the index but are in the where clause. That could be it.

Comment: @PeterBrand unfortunately not. The `root` user can make this query using the index, not the filesort, so it's not that. Double checking this by removing those keys from the query still has the bad behaviour when run by the `readonly` user

Comment: Test with a user other than root that has full privileges, or grant indexing privilege to readonly to see if that makes a difference. The index is there and doesn't require privilege to use it, so it sounds like a bug to me. Maybe flush privileges? Have you contacted mysql tech support?